# Your render method should have return statement react/require-render-return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Person from "./Person/Person";

class Persons extends Component {
  render() {
    this.props.persons.map((person, index) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Person
            click={() => this.props.clicked(index)}
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            key={person.id}
            changed={event => this.props.changed(event, person.id)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}

export default Persons;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to provide a problem description. This might prevent ambigious answers or wrong answers. It also helps people who will have the same issue as you. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a React component you need to return your JSX. If this is a functional one it is simply like this:

```
function Component() {
    return <div>Some JSX</div>;
}
```

If it is a class component, your `render` method should return some JSX.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() { return <div>Some JSX</div>; }
}
```

Your code has only one return and this is for your `map`. So, put your code inside a top `return.`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Person from "./Person/Person";

class Persons extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.persons.map((person, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Person
                click={() => this.props.clicked(index)}
                name={person.name}
                age={person.age}
                key={person.id}
                changed={event => this.props.changed(event, person.id)}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Persons;
```

Comment: You are welcome. As @5th points out in the comments, it is better to explain your problem with a few sentences in your question and keep the title a little bit clean :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class ProfileService extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
}

 render(){        
   <div>
      fdgsdfgsdfg sdfgsdfg
   </div>        
 }
}
```

you should add the return in the render method.

```
 render(){
        return(
            <div>
                fdgsdfgsdfg sdfgsdfg
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply return your JSX in render (With React v16+)

```
....
    render () {
            **return** this.props.persons.map((person, index) => {
                return (
                    <div>...
```

Wrap you map returning array of elements in a another elements for instance div for React v15 or lower